# How to bring back Mac Notes from external drive?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I recently erased my hard drive and installed Sierra from USB flash, to start fresh.
Before doing this, I copied the main 3 files of Notes to external drive.
These are: NotesV6.storedata, NotesV6storedata-shm, NotesV6storedata-wal
I copied them from: com.Apple.Notes>Data>Library>Notes

I drag the existing V6 files to the desktop, and instead I paste the copied ones from external drive.But nothing happens.
I'm probably doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable the "on my computer" account first. In retrospect you should probably have used iCloud for storing your notes instead.